# Read the xml in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have this type of xml

```
    <root>
     <Message code="AC_CONNECTOR__FAIL_IN_CONNECT"        
                id="AR_AC_CONNECTOR__FAIL_IN_CONNECT" 
                bundleName="Error" locale="pt" severity="4" userFlag="">

              (AR1-000001) Error in the data
     </Message>
     <Message code="AC_CONNECTOR__FAIL_IN_DISCONNECT"      
                id="AR_AC_CONNECTOR__FAIL_IN_DISCONNECT" bundleName="Error"      
                locale="pt" severity="4" userFlag="">

          (AR1-000001) error
     </Message>
   </root>
```

and i want it to be read in the javascript 
after reading this i need to replace value of the message with another based on the `code` property of the message
i have done this code ...

```
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Reading XML</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

           function readXML() {
           var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xml.open('GET', 'error1.xml', false);
           xml.send();
           var xmldata = xml.responseXML;
           document.write("Nutan");


          xmldata = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml.responseText, 'text/xml');

          var emp = xmldata.getElementsByTagName("ptr");
          // document.write(emp);
            var output=emp[0].getElementsByTagName("Message")[0].firstChild.data;
          document.write(output);

  }
 </script>
      </head>
       <body>
          <h1>
            XMl file
          </h1>
          <button onclick="readXML()">Read xml file</button>
       </body>
  </html>
```

but this code is not reading the xml file ..which is in above format
please help me to read xml file with above format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the `code` value you have to use the `getAttribute("code")` function [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/met_element_getattribute.asp), if you want to list the `code` value for each child the following code is working.

```
  <html>

        <head>
        <script>
function readXML() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            myFunction(xhttp);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "error1.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Message");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var node_code = x[i].getAttribute("code");
        document.write(node_code + " ");
        var node_value = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.write(node_value + " <br>");
    }
}
        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <button onclick="readXML()">Read xml file</button>
        </body>

        </html>
```

It's better if you separate your JS code from your HTML by using two separate files. If this isn't what you are looking for please explain your problem better.

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for ...now i have to get the value of the Message tag can you please help me out there ?

Comment: If the answer is correct can you please flag it? Thanks :)

Comment: but it is not reading the contents of my xml file ..did you have some idea ?

Comment: What error do you get? The code I've posted is working on Chrome and Mozilla, plus I've tried it on Codepen and the script works, I can't link it to you because I can't upload your XML file on the site.

Comment: that was browser's issue

Comment: So now it is working? In that case please mark as answered